# Mediawiki: Getting jobs to run on edit on wiki farm/family

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki

I've set up a Wiki family consisting of a small number of Wikis that have (and are expected to continue having) low to moderate traffic.

When you run a single MediaWiki, it runs a job on every page request which is nice for keeping links and categories up to date, but I can't get this behaviour to work for a wiki family.

I have a wiki setup with a branching localSettings (depending on the SERVER_NAME) and have despite searching (and asking on Mediawiki) found no way to keep this job behaviour, rather I get jobs queueing up, presumably because the maintenance scripts being automatically run do not know which Wiki they originate from.

Is there a way to fix/circumvent this? I have not found any kind of variable being supplied when the job queue is run that could be passed into the localSettings.php so that the correct settings are loaded and the jobs can run properly.

Comment: Problem found - the issue was that the wikis were behind a permission gate (just a regular Apache one), and async jobs don't inherit the permissions, so I had to set async jobs to false to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally jobs are run on each page load within context of current Wiki, this means in your case there should be no problems with queue, because your LocalSettings file is branched. Though, in certain circumstances job queue may be overloaded, in this case you will need to disable default queue behavior ( by setting `$wgJobRunRate = 0;`) and configure maintenance scripts runner in crontab. This can be tricky for branched farm, but i think it will work like that:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/your/wiki/maintenance/runJobs.php --wiki domainA.com
* * * * * php /path/to/your/wiki/maintenance/runJobs.php --wiki domainB.com
* * * * * php /path/to/your/wiki/maintenance/runJobs.php --wiki domainC.com
```

In this scenario during script execution two constants will be available in LocalSettings.php: `MW_DB` and `MW_PREFIX` (use only MW_DB), so you will need to modify your LocalSettings.php like that:

```
...
$activeWiki = 'defaultWiki';
$switchVar = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if( defined('DO_MAINTENANCE') && defined('MW_DB') ) {
    $switchVar = MW_DB;
}
switch( $switchVar ) {
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with the setup there ARE problems with the queue - even making sure that the queue is empty (by running runJobs manually for it - which works if you set the SERVER_NAME var), and having jobrunrate set even higher than it should be (I set it to 3 for this test, and on a wiki that is behind a password meaning no other traffic is going on), triggering page requests never progresses the queue at all.

It's possible that I could get around it by setting a cron, but I'm trying to see if I can get the page request one working, since that'd mean it'd be more responsive.

Comment: There is a chance that your job queue is stuck ( because of failing job or something else ). You can try to manually clean your 'jobs' table and watch how it will go after that.

Comment: Just tried that, with no success. The main reason I think it's something to do with the branching/wikifarm setup is that if I remove the branching stuff and have it set up to just be a single wiki, the jobs get done. But once I have it branching with the wiki family, no jobs get done at all.

I'm wondering if for some reason the SERVER_NAME doesn't get sent with the queue trigger, but I don't know where the code for that would be hiding to check it out.

Comment: Update - I've put some debug logging into the localSettings file to see if something might mess up the branching, but as far as I can tell the branching variable is always set correctly, meaning that I'm not sure WHY the job queue isn't firing as it should.

Comment: Update - I found the problem. See main above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found - the issue was that the wikis were behind a permission gate (just a regular Apache one), and async jobs don't inherit the permissions, so I had to set async jobs to false to solve it.

In case anyone else gets this problem - $wgRunJobsAsync = false; should be added to localSettings.php